# What is port 989 used for in FTPS?

Tags: port, firewall, implicit, ftps

For Implicit FTPS connections, port 990 is the standard control channel port to initiate the connection.
With Passive FTPS the server then specifies a port to use for the data channel from a preconfigured range.
A lot of documentation also specifically mentions port 989, but doesn't say at what point this port would be used.

What is port 989 actually used for in FTPS, and is it necessary to open the server firewall on this port?

Comment: [990/TCP for the FTPS control channel, and port 989/TCP for the FTPS data channel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) -- so the equivalent of port 21 in FTP.

Comment: @dratenik, the server specifies a random port from a separate range to use for the data channel.  Whats the difference between 989 and the random port that the server chooses?

Comment: 989 serves as the port for the initial connection.  A modern server than picks some other port but initial connection is done on one of the default ports depending on the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

**FTPS in implicit mode:** An increasingly obsolete mode that requires an established SSL session prior to any exchange of data. Uses port **989** for the data channel and port **990** for the control channel.

**FTPS in explicit mode (aka FTPES):** Uses port **20** for the data channel and port **21** for the control channel. Both unencrypted FTP and encrypted FTPS are supported. The client and server negotiate the level of protection used. Control channel encryption is requested by sending either the AUTH TLS command or the AUTH SSL command. Data channel encryption is requested with the PROT command.

Source: https://community.infosecinstitute.com/discussion/88165/ftps-port-number-s

**Port 989** is registered with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=15) are shown as official port for FTPS.

In **active mode**, the client connects to the server on the ports above and lets the the server know what port the client wants to use.

In **passive mode**, the client still connects to the default port but lets the server pick which other port to use.

Source:  https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified

Comment: Thanks, Is port 989 only used in 'active' FTPS, since 'passive' FTPS uses a random port chosen by the server for the data channel?

Comment: In active mode, the client will tell the serve what port to use and it has to be higher than 1024.  In passive mode, the default port is only used if no other port is setup for FTP on the server.  The default port would normally be 20 with 989 used if SSL is required.  More info here:  https://titanftp.com/2018/08/23/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp/

Comment: I added a better explanation to the answer.